# Query Using Entity Framework Error with Database Table name Error

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I want to get some data of database in C#.
But my LINQ Query was connected invalid database table.

DataContext.cs

```
namespace BlackBoxSOS.Models
{
  public class DataContext : DbContext 
  {

    public DbSet<ServiceIdentification> ServiceIdentifications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ObservationDatum> ObservationData { get; set; }

    ....

  }
}
```

Function In Service.svc.cs

```
public GetObservationResponseTypeMessage GetObservation(GetObservationTypeMessage request)
    {

        DataContext dataContext = new DataContext();

            var result = dataContext.ObservationData;

            ....
        return ...;
    }
```

Variable result is "SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Res_Value] AS [Res_Value]
    FROM [dbo].[ObservationDatums] AS [Extent1]" when executing my code. But DataContext has DbSet ObservationData, not ObservationDatums.

Why this program has error? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customise the table name used by Entity Framework code first by applying the table attribute to the ObservationDatum type, or by using the Fluent API (override OnModelCreating in the DbContext).

e.g.:

```
[Table("ObservationData")]
public class ObservationDatum
{
}
```

Or:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ObservationDatum>().ToTable("ObservationData");
}
```

Comment: I changed code that you advise me. But, Running `Update-Databse -ConnectionStringName MyConnection` gets error `Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.` I don't know what I missed.

Comment: If you're changing the code first model, then you need to run Add-Migration to scaffold the change, then update the database, unless you've dropped and recreated the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your table names are singular, you could try disabling table name pluralisation using the following code in your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. But Database table name is ObservationData.